# Based on long-format date column in a data.table, reduce cols in wide-format data.table

Tags: r, data.table, melt

I have a wide-format `data.table` like so:

```
library(data.table)
dt_wide <- data.table(
  "id" = seq(1:10),
  "yw_1001" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1002" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1003" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1004" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1005" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1006" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1007" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1008" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1009" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1010" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1011" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1012" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1013" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1014" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1015" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1016" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1017" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1018" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1019" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1020" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1021" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1022" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1023" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1024" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1025" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1026" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1027" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1028" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1029" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1030" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1031" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1032" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1033" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1034" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1035" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1036" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1037" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1038" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1039" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1040" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1041" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1042" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1043" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1044" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1045" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1046" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1047" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1048" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1049" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1050" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1051" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1052" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) )
  )
```

The cols correspond to year (first two digits) and week number (last to digits).

In my actual dataset (nrow=5,500,000, ncol=1400), I cannot `data.table::melt` because it would create a data.table over the row limit.

In reality, I only need values from certain week numbers. Take the following data.table

```
dt2 <- data.table(
  "id" = seq(1:10),
  "date" = sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2010/12/31'), by="day"), 10)
)
```

I need to keep the values in dt_wide that are 5, 10, and 15 weeks after the date in in `dt2` for each unique `id`. Ideally, want to reduce col size in dt_wide so I can melt to long format.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please use `set.seed` while generating random data. Also show expected output for the data shared. It is not clear to me how `dt2` is related to `dt_wide`. Also how column name `yw_1001` corresponds to year and week number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way that you can do with some mutations capitalizing on **dplyr, tidyr, stringr and lubridate packages**:

```
# Calling required libraries
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

# Creating dataframe
dt_wide <- data.table(
  "id" = seq(1:10),
  "yw_1001" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1002" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1003" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1004" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1005" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1006" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1007" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1008" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1009" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1010" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1011" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1012" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1013" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1014" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1015" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1016" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1017" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1018" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1019" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1020" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1021" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1022" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1023" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1024" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1025" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1026" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1027" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1028" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1029" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1030" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1031" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1032" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1033" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1034" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1035" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1036" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1037" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1038" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1039" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1040" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1041" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1042" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1043" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1044" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1045" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1046" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1047" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1048" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1049" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1050" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1051" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) ),
  "yw_1052" = trunc( runif(10,0,100) )
)

# Creating dataframe with point of interest
dt2 <- data.table(
  "id" = seq(1:10),
  "date" = sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2010/12/31'), by="day"), 10)
)

# Mutating data to get only required columns
columns_to_select <-
  dt2 %>%
  # Getting dates after 5/10/15 weeks
  mutate(after5 = date + (7 * 5),
         after10 = date + (7 * 10),
         after15 = date + (7 * 15)) %>%
  # Converting dates from wide format to long format
  tidyr::gather(key = "key", value = req_date, -c(id, date)) %>%
  # Converting date into respective column name in dt_wide dataframe
  mutate(year = format(as.Date(req_date), "%y"),
         week = stringr::str_pad(lubridate::week(req_date), 2, "left", "0"),
         select_date = paste0("yw_", year, week)) %>%
  # Selecting only required column into a vector
  select(select_date) %>%
  pull()

# Choosing from the wide dataframe only required columns
dt_wide %>%
  select(id, contains(columns_to_select))

# id yw_1024 yw_1044 yw_1017 yw_1014 yw_1045 yw_1031 yw_1035 yw_1029 yw_1049 yw_1022 yw_1019 yw_1050 yw_1036 yw_1040 yw_1034 yw_1027 yw_1041
# 1:  1      59       7      11       7      93      19      83      48      75      94      19       9      93      41       6      26      18
# 2:  2      84      22      18      70      29      53      63      26      23      12      93      84      17      57      96      93      98
# 3:  3       4      72      56      35      65      73      58      91      27      65      58       5      62      13      36      79      26
# 4:  4      36       5      26      56      34      27      60      64      79      27      40      64      32       0      96      56      19
# 5:  5      44      82      78      23      71      78      36      43      63      95      91      37      21      87      63      73      25
# 6:  6      46      45      81      89      59       0      85       3      68      23      90      82      93      42      28      67      32
# 7:  7      56      32       7      26      49      31      79      93      14      45      25      79      39      64      64      86      91
# 8:  8      82      99      46      79      81      56      39      10      20      27      83      29      30      30      35      96      24
# 9:  9      10      87      28      40      51      41      95      43      62      59      44      19      72      76      27      65      36
# 10: 10      81      19      44      55      22      53      98      54      16      29      30      28      20       2       5      39      23
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using `data.table` (and the `lubridate` package for dates). Since your issue appears to build from memory constraints, simply call `melt()` for each row in your (small) ID table using only the necessary columns. Note, too, that we have to check to see if a given date exists in `dt_wide` because some dates are not present.

```
rbindlist(lapply(1:nrow(dt2), function(x) {
  rowid <- dt2[x, id]
  rowdate <- dt2[x, date]
  
  dates <- rowdate + lubridate::weeks(c(5, 10, 15))
  cols <- paste0("yw_", strftime(dates, "%y%W"))
  
  # Because some dates aren't in the table
  cols <- intersect(cols, colnames(dt_wide))
  if (!length(cols)) return(NULL)
  
  melt(dt_wide[id == rowid, c("id", cols), with = F], id.vars = "id")
}))
```